# PHP variables not available inside while loop

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, while-loop, global

I have PHP variables that come from an ajax call. However, they are undefined when they go through the if statement, and the while loop, how do i fix this. I cannot get anything to work.

```
$userID = $_POST['id'];
$clubID = $_POST['clubID'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$delAtt = $_POST['delAtt'];
```

Rest of Code

```
if($delAtt == 1)
{
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM events WHERE clubID = "'.$clubID.'"');

    while ($row == mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

        $eventID = $row['eventID'];
        echo $eventID;

         mysql_query('DELETE FROM eventmember WHERE userID = "'.$userID.'" AND eventID = "'.$eventID.'"');
         mysql_query('DELETE FROM eventmember2 WHERE userID = "'.$userID.'" AND eventID = "'.$eventID.'"');
         mysql_query('DELETE FROM eventmember3 WHERE userID = "'.$userID.'" AND eventID = "'.$eventID.'"');

         mysql_query('DELETE FROM attendance WHERE userID = "'.$userID.'" AND eventID = "'.$eventID.'"');
         mysql_query('DELETE FROM attendance2 WHERE userID = "'.$userID.'" AND eventID = "'.$eventID.'"');
         mysql_query('DELETE FROM attendance3 WHERE userID = "'.$userID.'" AND eventID = "'.$eventID.'"');

     }
}
```

All the variables work inside the if statement, but not inside the while loop

Comment: There isn't anything wrong, do you do an ajax POST or GET? besides, check spelling, it is case sensitive.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting inside the if {} block? Maybe delAtt is 2 or "1"

Comment: i set it to 1 just for testing, also, when i echo $clubID it works inside the if {} statement, but not inside the while loop

Comment: That would be expected if you don't have any events with the posted clubID in your database.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli).

Comment: In line with what @tereško wrote: read up on **SQL Injection**. It will save you quite some headache in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['delAtt'])){
    $userID = $_POST['id'];
    $clubID = $_POST['clubID'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $delAtt = $_POST['delAtt'];
}
else{
    $delAtt = 0
}

// Rest of code
```

And correct assignment this line:

```
while ($row == mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            ^
```

To:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

Comment: but, i manually set the variables after the posts to test the code, and it still doesn't work

Comment: be sure that `$_POST` has any value. `var_dump($_POST);` to show.

Comment: All the variables work inside the if statement, but not inside the while loop

Comment: Did you correct assignment in while loop and has still issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always put a check for POST variables like below:

```
if (isset($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["id"])) { //TO DO }
```

So that it is easier for you to know whether your POST variables are really post to the receive page.

The following code can show you what you have in POST variable array.

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: but, i manually set the variables after the posts to test the code, and it still doesn't work

Comment: All the variables work inside the if statement, but not inside the while loop